# Embedded OS X Bundle Xcode Guidance

Tags: objective-c, xcode, macos

I'm creating a OS X application that I intend to have a plug-in architecture. The plugins will be loaded dynamically. *I wish to have a number of default bundles included in the application package contents but I am at an impasse with Xcode 4.x*.

Is it the best approach to create another project in the Xcode workspace and deal with it that way or is creating different targets (schemes?) in the application project a better practice?

Any opinions, guidance, experience is thanked in advance

--Frank

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would create additional targets in your project for each of the plug-ins.  Then, add a copy files build phase in your app the copies the plug-in into your apps's plug-ins folder.